# No Sound When Exporting Java Project to .JAR

Tags: java, audio, jar, executable-jar

Been making a 2d platformer game and just got some custom music made for the game. The music/in game sound effects play fine when I run them from Eclipse, my IDE, but once the game is exported into a JAR file, everything functions normally except theres no sound. None of the effects, none of the music.

Here's the code for the class that handles the audio playing:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioPlayer {
    
    private Clip clip;
    
    public AudioPlayer(String s) {
        
        try {
            
            AudioInputStream ais =
                AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                    getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                        s
                    )
                );
            AudioFormat baseFormat = ais.getFormat();
            AudioFormat decodeFormat = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                16,
                baseFormat.getChannels(),
                baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                false
            );
            AudioInputStream dais =
                AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                    decodeFormat, ais);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(dais);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void play() {
        if(clip == null) return;
        stop();
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        if(clip.isRunning()) clip.stop();
    }
    
    public void close() {
        stop();
        clip.close();
    }
    
}
```

And here's how the sound is called in other classes:

```
        bgMusic = new AudioPlayer("/Music/level1-1.mp3");
        bgMusic.play();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you shure that your path "/Music/level1-1.mp3" is pointing to the same place as it was during programing in Eclipse?

Comment: So this is the weird part with the folder organization. In Eclipse, there are two main folders, src and resources. However, when I export to a jar and then unzip, it looks like this https://gyazo.com/027ae1fdfd95f7a8728c752f70ec7c88. All the folders that were in "resources" or "source" are all now together. But everything still functions properly except the sound. I dont understand.

Comment: @MichaelFehr please read above comment. Im somewhat new to coding and dont understand the concept of how the path would be different when exported

Comment: You are **loading** the mp3-file from an external source and - so far I can read your code - **not** from something that is located in "source" or "resources" so the AudioPlayer has no direct access to your file.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Heres the file organization in eclipse: https://gyazo.com/86cc7fcbf0cd2beb0ea9d9123294ffb4

As you can see, the sound files are within resources, not located externally. When I extract the jar file they are still in there. But they dont play

Comment: Try going to 'build path' and under the source tab, see if your resource directory is there.   I think you need  to be doing a "this.getClass().getResource(...)" .

Comment: @cliff2310 the resource directory is under the build path. I also added this.getClass().getResource("/Music/level1-1.mp3");

Still not functioning

Comment: IDK why the sound plays when you are in Eclipse. mp3's aren't supported and usually require a library such as Javazoom for their playback. How did you get the files to play in Eclipse?

Comment: I think 'getResourceAsStream' is right for you.  The only other thing is I always use "resource"  and you have"Resource"?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner all the code i used is here. I did nothing special, the mp3's just work. Ive tried using ogg before, that didnt work.